# How can I attach this triangle with cardview in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, view, android-recyclerview, android-components

is there any specific component in Android or I have to use view to make triangle (showing in round in image) and attach to card but still as I uploaded image it would not be as same as in image.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Well there are many approaches , but mine is :***

You will create an Image like that in photoshop (Of course measure it well and Target all devices (***dp***)), then place it inside your `drawable` folder , and call it on top of your CardView.

Suppose that image is called `image_traingle.jpg`  you can do it this way

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:onClick="Contract"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Imageview
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:src="drawable/image_triangle"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                  .
                  .
                  .
        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: thanks for reply. but there is a component in android called extra detail, i forgot the exact name i am searching since last two days but i could not able to find. i will try this approach @LuttayaHuzaifahIdris.

Comment: Okay @kuldeepzala, if you don't mind , you can give me a Tick

Comment: sure i will :) @LuttayaHuzaifahIdris

Comment: @kuldeepzala Do you mind to tell me how you proceed?